# PHP combine 2 strings

Tags: php, sql

I have searched around for the answer to this but everything I try gives me an error.

I have a php function:

```
function _buildQueryCategoryK2Multiple(){
    $query="select id,title,alias,catid,introtext FROM #__k2_items where published=1 and catid=17";
    return $query;
}
```

Basically I would like to add another line to $query, something like:

```
function _buildQueryCategoryK2Multiple(){
    $query1="select id,title,alias,catid,introtext FROM #__k2_items where published=1 and catid=17";
    $query2="select id,title,alias,catid,introtext FROM #__k2_items where published=1 and catid=18";
    return $query1.$query2;
}
```

If I do this though I get an error. Does anyone know the correct way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: What do you really want to do (apart from appending strings) and what is the error?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Find records where the `catid` is either 17 or 18?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SQL IN STATEMENT

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

If you want to get 17 and 18, use SQL `IN` statement instead of copying whole query, what will be if you want to select 100 ids? you'll send kilobytes of queries to db ?

**Example**:

```
 function _buildQueryCategoryK2Multiple(){
//if ids you are getting in array, you can implode it to string with ',' and put the string variable instead of '17,18'
        $query="select id,title,alias,catid,introtext FROM #__k2_items where published=1 and catid in (17, 18)";
        return $query;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a semicolon to your **`$query1`** here as shown

```
$query1="select id,title,alias,catid,introtext FROM #__k2_items where published=1 and catid=17;";
                                                                 -----------------------------^
```

You need to separate multiple SQL statements using a **`;`**

If you were using [`MySQL WorkBench`](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), you could have found it.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the queries with **`;`** 
One way is using `implode()` :

```
function _buildQueryCategoryK2Multiple(){

    $query[]="select id,title,alias,catid,introtext FROM #__k2_items where published=1 and catid=17";
    $query[]="select id,title,alias,catid,introtext FROM #__k2_items where published=1 and catid=18";
    return implode(";",$query);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon is an issue as it delineates the end of a MySQL command line. So you need to add that to the end of each line. Also while some will recommend concatenating the queries, a simpler way that is a tad more flexible—at least from my real world use of scenarios like this—is to create an array & use `implode()` on it. So your code like this.

```
function _buildQueryCategoryK2Multiple(){

    $query = array();
    $query[] = "select id,title,alias,catid,introtext FROM #__k2_items where published=1 and catid=17;";
    $query[] = "select id,title,alias,catid,introtext FROM #__k2_items where published=1 and catid=18;";

    return implode(' ', $query);

}
```

Another more elegant option based on the queries you have presented is to send an array of values to the function.

```
function _buildQueryCategoryK2Multiple($catid_array = array()){

    if (empty($catid_array)) {
        $catid_array = array(17,18);
    }

    $query = array();
    foreach ($catid_array as $catid) {
        $query[] = sprintf("select id,title,alias,catid,introtext FROM #__k2_items where published=1 and catid=%d;", $catid);
    }

    return implode(' ', $query);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You an concat the two strings with some special characters like "|" or "#" etc and return the single string.

In the calling function you can split the two string with the special character you used and use separately.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Need to be add `;` end of every `select` statment

```
function _buildQueryCategoryK2Multiple(){
    $query1="select id,title,alias,catid,introtext FROM #__k2_items where published=1 and (catid=17 OR  catid=18); ";
    $query2="select id,title,alias,catid,introtext FROM #__k2_items where published=1 and catid=18; ";
    return $query1.' '.$query2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array format as

```
function _buildQueryCategoryK2Multiple(){

    $returnArr = array();

    $returnArr['query1'] ="select id,title,alias,catid,introtext FROM #__k2_items where published=1 and catid=17";

    $returnArr['query2'] ="select id,title,alias,catid,introtext FROM #__k2_items where published=1 and catid=18";

    return $returnArr;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
function _buildQueryCategoryK2Multiple()
 {
    $query="select id,title,alias,catid,introtext FROM #__k2_items where published=1 and catid=17";
    $query .= " union all "
    $query .= "select id,title,alias,catid,introtext FROM #__k2_items where published=1 and catid=18";
    return $query;
    }
```

or

```
function _buildQueryCategoryK2Multiple()
{
    $query="select id,title,alias,catid,introtext FROM #__k2_items where published=1 and catid in (17,18,19) ";
    return $query;
}
```